# dynamic drop down using text file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created Dynamic drop down with text file to load on second drop down list

- now my question is how do i display second drop down only when user select any option from first box

### code

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#text-one").change(function() {
            $("#text-two").load("textdata/" + $(this).val() + ".txt");
        });
              });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page-wrap">
    <h1>Pulls from text files</h1>
    <select id="text-one">
        <option selected value="base">Please Select</option>
        <option value="beverages">Beverages</option>
        <option value="snacks">Snacks</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <select id="text-two">
        <option>Please choose from above</option>
    </select>

</div>
</body>
```

i need display second drop down only when user select first one

full working

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sanoj908572/8hthxvf2/)

### snacks.txt

```
<option value="coffee">Coffee</option>
<option value="coke">Coke</option>
```

Comment: can you show the file to be loaded? are there options with tags?

Comment: what does txt file contain json or html option list ????

Comment: @Fahad added txt file only two line i have in my txt file when i select snacks i first box only then the second box should appear untill it should be hidden

Comment: how can make work this without `JQuery` because the above example works with only jQuery but i don't use `jquery` form my page for this one method i need to add `jquery` is there any way to work without use of `jQuery`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put second dropdown as hidden as default

```
<select id="text-two" style="display :none">
        <option>Please choose from above</option>
    </select>
```

And inside on change of first dropdown, show it

```
$(function() {
        $("#text-one").change(function() {
            $("#text-two").show();
            $("#text-two").load("textdata/" + $(this).val() + ".txt");
        });
              });
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/8hthxvf2/2/

Javscript fiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/RahulB007/Lnenuohd/

Comment: how do i display a tic symbol right of first drop box when its loaded the second

Comment: You need to add an hidden icon right next to first dropdown and show the icon once the dropdown is loaded

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sanoj908572/8hthxvf2/ check my fiddle i can't display symbol when its loaded

Comment: I can't see any image icon next to first dropdown in fiddle. You need to add an image icon which is hidden by default.

Comment: its not using image icon am using css <span id="checkmark">

Comment: put $("#checkmark").show() in the success method where text-one is populated

Comment: how can make work this without `JQuery` because the above example works with only `jQuery` but i don't use `jquery` form my page for this one method i need to add `jquery` is there any way to work without use of jQuery

Comment: @sanojlawrence : added a javascript fiddle!

Answer (score 2):

if txt file is something like this

Example : snacks.txt

```
<option value="a">A</option>
<option value="b">B</option>
<option value="c">C</option>
```

javascript code

```
$("#text-one").change(function() {
    $.get( "textdata/" + $(this).val() + ".txt", function(data) {
        $("#text-two").html( data );
    });
});
```

**EDITED CODE**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
       $("#text-one").change(function() {
           if(this.value != 'base'){
                $.get( "textdata/" + this.value + ".txt", function(data) {
                    $("#text-two").html( data ).show();
                });
           }else{
                $("#text-two").hide();
           }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page-wrap">
        <h1>Pulls from text files</h1>
        <select id="text-one">
            <option selected value="base">Please Select</option>
            <option value="beverages">Beverages</option>
            <option value="snacks">Snacks</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <select id="text-two" style="display: none;">
            <option>Please choose from above</option>
        </select>

    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
<select id="text-one">
        <option selected value="base">Please Select</option>
        <option value="beverages">Beverages</option>
        <option value="snacks">Snacks</option>
    </select>
<select id="text-two" style="display :none">

    </select>
```

JS:

```
$("#text-one").change(function() {

       if ($(this).val() != 'base')
       {
           $("#text-two").show();
          $("#text-two").load("textdata/" + $(this).val() + ".txt");

       }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/chakrei/8hthxvf2/4/) fiddle

Code modified

```
    $(function () {
    $("#text-one").change(function () {
        if($('#text-one option:selected').index() >= 1)
            $('#text-two').show();        
        else
            $('#text-two').hide();

        $("#text-two").load("textdata/" + $(this).val() + ".txt");
    });
    $('#text-two').hide();
});
```